# Can I use OSX Native VPN settings instead of Cisco Anyconnect

Tags: macos, vpn, macos-sierra, cisco-anyconnect

A client requires that I connect via the "Cisco AnyConnect Secure Mobility Client", through which I enter servername, username and password. It works. But I'd like to use the Build-in VPN settings provided by Mac OS-X (Sierra) instead. Here I have three options (L2TP, Cisco IPSec or IKEv2). I've tried the Cisco IPSec option and entered the server name and credentials that I have working with Cisco AnyConnect, but this is not working.

So my question; Is it only possible to use the Cisco Client? It's not very user friendly and doesn't allow to remember the password (I guess that's why I have to use it) ...

Answer (score 3):

I'll bet your client's IT security group set the VPN standard and require the use of the Cisco client to connect to their network.  Many companies do this.  If you don't use it, likely you won't connect, or if you do you could find yourself disconnected, flagged as a security breach....  And if you have to use any shared files or resources on the client's network, it's likely that only through the Cisco client will this be allowed.  With all that....

Here's the link to Cisco's support page for the [AnyConnect client](https://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/support/security/anyconnect-secure-mobility-client/tsd-products-support-series-home.html).

Now, you've installed the package on your Mac, you've got login credentials. Your client should have given you configuration settings to go with your credentials.  The logs for the client are in /opt/cisco/vpn -- you should look in there and see what/any error messages you are getting.

Your connection options are Layer 2 tunneling (L2TP), IPSec and IKE42 (IKE is Internet Key Exchange). Per Cisco's support pages you need 4.3 MR3 for Sierra to work, do you have that installed? Once you've checked that out, then I'd set it for IPSec and try to connect.

If you continue to have problems, you should contact your client's IT group; I've seen odd parameters with VPN's and you want to make sure you have all the information you need.

Answer (score 1):

Anyconnect can use IPSec or SSL VPN connections. This is determined by your infrastructure design. OSX does not natively support SSL VPN, so if that's your company uses then you cannot use the native OSX VPN options.

For any connect to remember the password, it also has to be set by your company on the server side. The any connect client checks with the server to enable or disable password saving.